# Отправка смс со своего номера через интернет

Tags: php, sms

Частенько с сайта отправляются смс. Сейчас пользуюсь [ЧилиСМС](http://chilisms.ru/)
. но теперь хочу реализовать отправку со своего номера. 
На [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/115037/) нашел интересную статью, которая подходит мне, но там ссылка на класс битая. 
Где можно найти этот класс или как еще можно реализовать данное решение?

Comment: Спросите у автора статьи через личные сообщения

Comment: я не зарегистрирован

Comment: @Радик Камалов, вы предлагаете нам зарегистрироваться за вас?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/synchrone/oms-php

Это наверно то, что тебе нужно